# query_posts doesnt show pages with given ID when post_type => page

Tags: query-posts, pages, include, post-type

At the moment I am working on a WP-site, which on the frontpages has 3 excerpts of other pages on it.
The code I am trying to use for this is as following:

```
<?php query_posts(array('post_type' => 'page',
                            'include' => 5, 7, 52,
                            'showposts' => 3) ); ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <div class="column">
            <h2 class="icon" id="page-column-id-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                </a>
            </h2>

            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
        <p>Sorry, het bericht is niet gevonden.<br />Probeer het later nog eens..</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Sadly, when I use this code I get a query for all the pages I have.
Anyone has any idea how to get only the 3 pages on ID using this method?

Thnx in advance

Comment: I found a fix already. After some more browsing through the wordpress-codex I found this nice string to add to the query in order to query page id's:

    'post__in' => array(7, 16, 52)

So that did the trick :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use "post__in", a example:

```
<?php
$ids = array(5, 7, 52);
query_posts(array('post_type' => 'page',
'post__in' => $ids,
'showposts' => 3) );
?>
```

Comment: thnx :) This will do the trick aswell, however I found another solution